# Rails 4 concern errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I've notice the new features of `concern` in rails4, and I read the document of it in http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html.
But it seems doesn't work as I expect. Here is my code of my `/models/concerns/current_user.rb`.

```
require 'active_support/concern'

module CurrentUser
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    def accessor_current_user
      attr_accessor :current_user
    end
  end

end

class ActiveRecord::Base
  include CurrentUser
end
```

You probably notice that last 3 lines of my code, that's because I want all my models can call the method and I think it may be a good way to achieve that. But when i start rails server, it just cannot call the `accessor_current_user` method. So I am confusing about this. I really don't know the reason. Hope someone can help me. :)

---

Update!
Finally, i found it's maybe a good way to create a `ActiveRecord::Base` class in the initializers fold, and then include the CurrentUser in the class.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
require 'active_support/concern'

module CurrentUser
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    attr_accessor :current_user
  end

  module ClassMethods
  end

end

class ActiveRecord::Base
  include CurrentUser
end
```

Then you should be able to do something like this:

```
foo = Foo.new
foo.current_user
```

Where `Foo` is:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord:Base
  include CurrentUser
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, can you explain this? I tried to add the last 2 lines but still can't work.

Comment: The last 2 lines are only here to illustrate. You should not add them. The basic ideas is to add an `attr_accessor` on any class that include your `CurrentUser` module. This is done with the `included` block.

Comment: Well, I know if I add `include CurrentUser` in the Foo class can work well, but that isn't what i want. Suppose you have 8 models need to call the `accessor_current_user` method, so in your way you need to add `include CurrentUser` in all the 8 models, i don't think it's best way. So i am wondering if i can write some code to achieve that goal.

Comment: Including your `CurrentUser` module for every `ActiveRecord::Base` sub classes is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are calling accessor_current_user is wrong. This way you can call `ActiveRecord::Base.accessor_current_user` method and it will execute the code without any error. And then you can call

> ```
> ar = ActiveRecord::Base.new
> ar.current_user = "foo"
> ar.current_user # this will return 'foo'
> ```

But the correct way to implement the attr_accessor using ActiveSupport::Concern is

> ```
> module CurrentUser
>   extend ActiveSupport::Concern
>
>   included do
>     attr_accessor :current_user
>   end
>
> end
> ```

If you are writing your code in rails, then you don't need `require 'active_support/concern'`. Please refer [http://blog.neerajk.com/articles/2014-11-26-is-active-support-concern-really-another-concern/](http://blog.neerajk.com/articles/2014-11-26-is-active-support-concern-really-another-concern)